# static variable in class is undefined in callback on app.listen

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I am just beginning to use typescript instead of javascript for writing my `node.js` apps. I am a bit confused.

I have this code which starts an express server

```
import * as express from 'express';

class Server {
    static expressApp: express.Express;
    static PORT: number = 3000;

    public static startServer():void {
        this.expressApp = express();
        console.log(this.PORT);
        this.expressApp.listen(this.PORT, this.serverStartedCallback)
    }

    private static serverStartedCallback():void {
        console.log("Server is listening on port " + this.PORT);
    }
}

Server.startServer();
```

I can get the value of the PORT variable in `startSever()`.

But in the callback `serverStarted()` the `this.PORT` variable is `undefined`.
Can someone elaborate as to why this is?

Comment: `this.constructor.serverStartedCallback`

Answer (score 0):

From the ["this parameters in callbacks"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) section:

> You can also run into errors with `this` in callbacks, when you pass
>   functions to a library that will later call them. Because the library
>   that calls your callback will call it like a normal function, **`this`
>   will be undefined.**

The most trivial fix to use the class name to pass the function instead of using `this`:

```
this.expressApp.listen(Server.PORT, Server.serverStartedCallback)
```

---

**Note:** In a non-static environment this problem could be easily solved by using arrow functions.

```
class Caller {
    call(method: () => void) { method(); }
}

class Server {
    caller: Caller = new Caller();
    PORT: number = 3000;

    public startServer(): void {
        this.caller.call(this.serverStartedCallback_Arrow);
        this.caller.call(this.serverStartedCallback_NonArrow);
    }

    private serverStartedCallback_Arrow = () => {
        console.log("Arrow Server is listening on port " + this.PORT);
    }

    private serverStartedCallback_NonArrow(): void {
        console.log("Nonarrow Server is listening on port " + this.PORT);
    }
}

var server = new Server();
server.startServer();
```

*Console:*

```
Arrow Server is listening on port 3000
Nonarrow Server is listening on port undefined
```